# the Caret of textbox don't disappear after override OnGotFocus and OnLostFocus

Tags: wpf, caret

I create a custom control, inherit from Textbox,and override the function OnGotFocus and OnLostFocus in control.

Then when I use the control, the Caret do not disappear after focus is lost.
I check the property IsFocused in function OnLostFocus, the value is false.But why the Caret do not disappear ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call the base class' methods, `base.OnGotFocus()` and `base.OnLostFocus()` after your custom logic in the child class.